# ByteBuddy IllegalStateException: Attachment provider cannot connect on current JVM

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I'm trying to mock a class that gets loaded by some process to return another value.

Say I have

```
Class A 
{ 
    public static IClassType getTheClass()
    { 
       new ClassB();
    } 
}
```

And I want that if some process calls `ClassA.getTheClass()` to return `ClassC` (which of course implements `IClassType`)

Somehow I figured out this should be possible with Byte Buddy's hot swapping capabilities. But I fail to install an agent.
I tried with the `-javaagent:C:\byte-buddy-agent-0.7.1.jar` switch wich gives me

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Byte Buddy agent is not installed or not accessible
```

as well as with `ByteBuddyAgent.install();` which produces

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attachment provider cannot connect on the current JVM: ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.Compound{attachmentProviders=[ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForJigsawVm.INSTANCE, ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForToolsJarVm.JVM_ROOT, ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForToolsJarVm.JDK_ROOT, ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForToolsJarVm.MACINTOSH]}
```

on my machine. Does this only work for OpenJDK? Am I missing something?

Comment: What VM are you using? The javaagent parameter should work for any JVM. The runtime dispatch only for OpenJDK and J9 JDKs.

Comment: I'm using JRE1.8.0-65 64bit on a Windows 7 64bit machine. Trying to start from within eclipse with the VM argument:
-javaagent:D:\_WORKFOLDER\ByteBuddy\byte-buddy-agent-0.7.1.jar

Comment: On a non-JDK VM, the runtime attachment will not work as it requires a *tools.jar* available. The approach with setting a javaagent should however work. Are you sure that you are poining to the correct file? I will look into this tomorrow and see if a recent update broke something.

Comment: I just tried to run a simple application using on a Windows machine and specified: `-javaagent:C:\\Users\\rafael.winterhalter\\.m2\\repository\\net\\bytebuddy\\byte-buddy-agent\\0.7.1\\byte-buddy-agent-0.7.1.jar` and it worked perfectly fine to read the agent at runtime using `ByteBuddyAgent.getInstrumentation()`- I think you need to add double slashes. Might that be the problem?

Comment: At least it provides some Instrumentation without any error (sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@69c81773). So that seems to work. Probably.
But when I try:
ClassReloadingStrategy strategy = ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent();
new ByteBuddy().redefine( Factory.class ).method( ElementMatchers.named( "getRuntime" ) ).intercept( FixedValue.value( new MockedRuntime() ) ).make()
                .load( Factory.class.getClassLoader(), strategy );

It gives me a 
UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)

Comment: Yes, HotSwap has strict limitations. You cannot change signatures and add or remove options. This is a current JVM limitation. Have a look at JEP-159. This will hopefully change in the future.

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain to me why this is conflicting with the restrictions?
I don't want to change the signature of a method but only make it return another value of the same type. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Try setting a disabled implementation context factory on the Byte Buddy istance. Chances are that there is a static initializer bein rebased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the `byte-buddy-agent.jar` until recently. Try using a newer version and it should function without a problem.

The `ByteBuddyAgent` does indeed only work on JVM's that support some form of `tools.jar`. (Currently, OpenJDK, OracleJDK and J9.)